# how to get a particular response direct as a Toast in android from httpclient without displaying in link

Tags: android, json, post, httpclient

I'm working with `HttpClient` Post request from Android.

So, My Aim is to Display One JSON Data to the link(working fine: `https://test1.intuitionsoftwares.com/paytm/name2.php`) And another data to App with a Toast without displaying it to the web-link.

```
    Response_Json={"requestGuid":null,"orderId":null,"status":"SUCCESS","statusCode":"QR_1020",
"statusMessage":"Data already exist for this Merchant with same Id.",
"response":{"path":"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAeAAAAHgAQAAAABVr4M4AAABa0lEQVR42u3cQZaCMAwAUFhxjDmqHtVjsLIzjwFtaEVn3JnfFQ/7s8xLk8pQ3lgDnASfh2Z9lZ+347ZleZzbXSMMw3BuPIZ8Oi94W5ffbbu3a0gYhuHseL6l03XbkpCnBZ/uIc8xN8MwDMMNfhgShmEYPsZN4QrDMAy/cOyPWfiPPQMYhuFPxw9HTp0a9vV5FQzD8Gfj47U1Tf91VwqGYfiDcZV6T221uq1prVabYz8Mw3BmPK3J9Bq2TSH1XproMAzDifEijs/6VdO0ig7DMJwcl/1vS5K9hg7ptM7uq0cYhmE4DuyHFcez/hBCnrodVxiG4bS47I/91Rh/V+TCMAwnxv3rTtUBv9MXuKVeGIbhxLh/1f56j1NqUd26h2EYzo4fDpcu4bpT6KrCMAzDRx8TKTHfVjefYBiG4d4nRqq3JYzxnxSuMAzDWXBz7O/g/t88YRiG0+InnxgJY/xxX7jCMAwnxW8sOAf+BgqoPrPRX9WZAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC","encryptedData":"281005040101WF6MQGASEW3N"}}
```

From Above JSON I want to display Only Path to link.(Its working fine)

```
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
```

But From Response_Json I want to display `Status: SUCCESS` to Android `Toast` but not in Link.

Code to get Response:

```
int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new
                            InputStreamReader(
                            conn.getInputStream()));
                    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
                    String line = "";

                    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line);
                        break;
                    }

                    in.close();
                    return sb.toString();
                } else {
                    return new String("false : " + responseCode);
                }
```

JSON Data I'm Sending is:

```
URL url = new URL("https://test1.intuitionsoftwares.com/paytm/name2.php"); //Intuition Server URL path

                JSONObject postDataParams = new JSONObject();
                postDataParams.put("MID", MID);
                postDataParams.put("key", key);
                postDataParams.put("orderId", Id);
                postDataParams.put("posId", posId);
```

And PHP Code to display Response:

```
$yummy = json_decode($output);
echo $yummy->response->path; //QRCode data
```

How Can I achieve this ?

Comment: Can you share code?

Comment: Ok, I will do it..

Answer (score 0):

Very first you create POJO for your response [You can create json to pojo from this website](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

Then by using getter/setter you can easily access your `"status": "SUCCESS"` and open your `Toast`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete parsing of your json response.

Please have a look.

```
private void parseResponse(String jsonString)
{
    try
    {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);

        String requestGuid = jsonObject.has("requestGuid") ? jsonObject.optString("requestGuid") : "";
        String orderId = jsonObject.has("orderId") ? jsonObject.optString("orderId") : "";
        String status = jsonObject.has("status") ? jsonObject.optString("status") : "";
        String statusCode = jsonObject.has("statusCode") ? jsonObject.optString("statusCode") : "";
        String statusMessage = jsonObject.has("statusMessage") ? jsonObject.optString("statusMessage") : "";
        JSONObject responseJson = jsonObject.has("response") ? jsonObject.optJSONObject("response") : new JSONObject();

        String path = responseJson.has("path") ? responseJson.optString("path") : "";
        String encryptedData = responseJson.has("encryptedData") ? responseJson.optString("encryptedData") : "";

    }
    catch (JSONException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

You just need to call this method by passing your json response

Comment: we can use Gson as well that will be much easier.